# Recursive function to get the minimum maximum and sum of an array of integers

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, function-definition

Hello I'm struggling a little bit, I can't really figure out how to initialize my *min *max and *sum variables so that it doesn't keep reinitializing in the loop

I did this and I'd like to get help regarding what changes I should make

```
void min_max_sum_rec(int arr[],int length,int *min,int *max,int *sum){

    if(length==1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(arr[0]<*min){
            *min = arr[0];
        }
        if(arr[0]>*max){
            *max = arr[0];
        }
        sum+=arr[0];
    }
    min_max_sum_rec(arr+1,length-1,min,max,sum);
}
```

for reference my professor did this:

```
void min_max_sum(int arr[],int length,int *min,int *max,int *sum){

    if(length== 1){
        *min=*max=*sum=*arr;
         return;
    }
    min_max_sum(arr+1,length-1,min,max,sum);

    *sum+=arr[0];
    *min = (*min<arr[0]?*min:arr[0]);
    *max = (*max>arr[0]?*max:arr[0]);
}
```

but I don't really understand since *min *sum and *max are not initialized and also can't understand the if statement.

Wouldn't it make it so that when we only have an array with one integer *max *min and *sum would have the same value so all we did before would be meaningless ?

Comment: Maybe your teacher expects the function to be (initially) called with `min_max_sum_rec(array, length, INT_MAX, INT_MIN, 0);`

Comment: "for reference my professor did this:" Did what? The last piece of code? Please edit your question

Comment: @pmg No... The function expects a pointer So you can't pass INT_MAX! And btw... pointers to uninitialized values are fine (in the last code example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is your professors code:

```
void min_max_sum(int arr[],int length,int *min,int *max,int *sum){

    if(length== 1){
        *min=*max=*sum=*arr;
         return;
    }
    min_max_sum(arr+1,length-1,min,max,sum);

    *sum+=arr[0];
    *min = (*min<arr[0]?*min:arr[0]);
    *max = (*max>arr[0]?*max:arr[0]);
}
```

and it's fine. But the documentation must clearly state that the function is only allowed to be called with values of `n` being greater than zero.

You ask:

> Wouldn't it make it so that when we only have an array with one integer *max *min and *sum would have the same value **so all we did before would be meaningless** ?

Well, no... because we did **not** do anything before!

Notice that all the comparision for max/min and the sum calculation is **after** the recursion ends.

In other words - the code keeps making recursive calls with shorter and shorter array until there is only one element. The value of that element (which is the last element of the original array) is then used for initializing max/min/sum. As the recursive calls return it's checked whether a previous element is larger/smaller in order to update max/min and also updates sum.

It's a nice and simple implementation **but**....

**This task should never be solved using recursion**

You should ask your professor for an assignment where recursion actually makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me understand what he did there

Comment: @Bob__ Well, adding an assert would be fine but it's not really solving anything... it just makes the program crash. So it's a documentation thing... the documentation needs to state: "When calling this function n must be greater than zero; otherwise the behavior is undefined" (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

The function can look the following way

```
void min_max_sum_rec( const int a[], size_t n ,int *min, int *max, int *sum )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        min_max_sum_rec( a + 1, n - 1, min, max, sum );

        if ( n == 1 ) 
        {
            *min = a[0];
            *max = a[0];
        }
        else
        {       
            if ( a[0] < *min ) *min = a[0];   
            if ( *max < a[0] ) *max = a[0];
        }
        *sum +=  a[0];
    }
    else
    {
        *min = *max = *sum = 0;
    }
}
```

That is the function at first calls itself until it gets an empty sub-array. In this case it initializers the objects *min, *max, and sum and returns to the caller.

As for your function implementation then at least  this if statement

```
if(length==1){
    return;
}
```

does not make a sense.

Also this modified if statement

```
if(length== 1){
    *min=*max=*sum=*arr;
     return;
}
```

is general incorrect because the use can pass to the function an argument for the parameter `length` equal to 0.

And this call

```
min_max_sum_rec(arr+1,length-1,min,max,sum);
```

shall be within the else statement.

Note: In the initial code I had a typo using sum instead of *sum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right. I have seen this at the last moment. The function has been updated.

Comment: In general, a reduction operation can be initialized with its identity element. For addition, that is zero. For multiplication, it is one. For minimum of `int`, it is `INT_MAX`. (For minimum of real numbers, it is ∞.) For maximum of `int`, it is `INT_MIN`. (For reals, −∞.) Generally the reduction of an empty set should be considered to be the identity element, so the zero case ought to set `*min` to `INT_MAX`, `*max` to `INT_MIN`, and `sum` to zero. Then this also serves as the base case, eliminating the need to treat length 1 separately.

Comment: Why do the recursion to `n == 0` ? Stop at 1. See the example in the question. Much easier

Comment: "the use can pass to the function an argument for the parameter length equal to 0." hmmm or -1, -2, etc. I guess the "contract" is `n > 0`

Comment: @4386427 n equal to 0 is a valid contract. At least the function calls itself for n equal to 0.:) Also for example strings can have a length equal to 0.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The last code example (the professors code) will **not** call itself with n equal zero and I'm sure the contract is `n > 0` as it makes no sense to call a function with a zero length array.

Comment: and why even continue to n is zero? In the `else` your code assigns max/min to zero but later there another `if` for n being 1 where you overwrite the zeros. It's rather pointless

Comment: @4386427: Certainly it makes sense to call some functions with a zero length array. This may arise naturally when a set is partitioned into various set, and the criteria for some subset happens to produce an empty set. It may be easier to let the function produce its “default” result than to add special code in the caller to handle such cases. And there are other circumstances in which it arises. As far as mathematicians are concerned, the sum of zero elements in is zero, and the product of zero elements is one (which is why 0! = 1).

Comment: @4386427: In general, for any reduction operation, the operation on zero elements produces its identity element, the element e such that, for all x, f(e, x) = x.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well.. okay... there may be cases where it makes sense but not for this task. It's just an extra step which is meaningless. For n equal zero you can't even assign INT_MIN/INT_MAX to max/min as it is absolutely wrong

Comment: @4386427: Sure it does. I have worked on commercial library routines for taking minimums, maximums, and sums. And they have to handle zero-length cases correctly. Another example of where these arise is a user (a client of the library) wants to take the minimum of some large or streaming vector. For the larger vector, they may perform cache strip mining on it (because it is composed with other operations, and doing the multiple operations in in-cache strips is more efficient than doing each operation serially on larger-than-cache strips)…

Comment: … The strip mining procedure may produce fragments, since the total vector length might not be a multiple of the strip length. Or it might produce a zero-length fragment if it is a multiple, or if other circumstances intervene. Then the find-the-minimum function ought to return a value that, when composed with the return value from other strips, produces the correct result. The correct value for that is the identity element. So this does make sense for a find-the-minimum function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And in that case you also have the rule that the original array/vector must fulfill `n>1`

Comment: @4386427: No, we do not. The software works as I have described, and introducing a needless constraint is less desirable. It imposes an added burden on the client and increases the risk of bugs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So you are telling me that calling your code with and empty set (an **original** empty set - not a part/subset of the original set) is supposed to generate the values INT_MAX, INT_MIN and zero? Strange, very strange, IMO. An empty set has no min/max or sum.

Comment: @4386427: Sure, why not? Observe that the routines may never be used with a **total** vector length of zero. Rather, the total vector will be strip-mined into segments, computations will be performed for each segment, and then the segment results will be combined into a final result. Since the total length is never zero, the identity element will never propagate through to the final result (unless it is in fact the correct mathematical result, as because all elements were `INT_MIN`). However, the fact it was returned for empty segments makes the composition of partial results work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "First, observe that the routines may never be used with a total vector length of zero." Exactly! That's my point... The code in this example does **not** break things down. It operates on one set so n must be greater than zero

Comment: @4386427: Then you are missing the point that there are individual calls with a length of zero, and those need to work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, in the professors code there are no "individual calls with a length of zero" but it do require that the **initial** call is **not** with an empty set. That's the contract... `n` **must** be grater than zero. That's why the professors code is shorter and simpler than the code in this answer.

Comment: @4386427: (a) I do not see any information in the posted question about what the professor’s calls to this routine are or what they are limited to. (b) I have been explaining to you general principles of design. By and large, called routines—or components of any system generally (mechanical, electrical, social, whatever) should lean toward being tolerant in what they accept.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Regarding your point b) : Maybe you should try to tell that to the C language designers... cause that is just not how the C standard functions work. There are so many contract and if you break them... bang!!! By making contracts you can often do simpler/faster implementations and it's done again and again in the world of C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Regarding your point a: : True, it isn't stated in the question but obvious when looking at the code

Comment: @4386427: You are correct, the professor’s implementation does not support zero-length calls. Nonetheless, the design principles I described above are valuable. The C standard library is irrelevant to that (some of it arose in attempting to codify prior implementations, so it was not able to prescribe improvements).